# Vue Js multiple components into the app.vue

Tags: vuejs2

I have the following code and i am getting the following error:

```
Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.
```

I want to include top and bottom navigation to the app.vue
How can i achieve that?

Main.js:

```
new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   router,
   template: '<App/>',
   components: { 'App':App }
})
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <navigationtop></navigationtop>
        <navigationbottom></navigationbottom>
        <router-view/>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import navigationtop from './components/navigation/top'
    import navigationbottom from './components/navigation/bottom'

    export default {
        name: 'app',
        components: {
            'navigationtop': navigationtop,
            'navigationbottom': navigationbottom
        }
    }......
```

Router:

```
export default new Router({
routes: [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    component: HelloWorld
  }
 ]
 })
```

HelloWorld:

```
<template> </template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'}}}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you include the code of the components being used at App component? The same for HelloWorld, It's possible that the problem is there.

Comment: you need `rende()` method inside your vue object

Comment: @dlopez updated code

Comment: @samayo how can i acieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to import your app like this:

```
import App from './foobar/App.vue'
```

and render it inside your Vue({}) object like:

```
new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   router,
   render: h => h(App)
})
```

Comment: And how can i render the top and bottom navigation?

Comment: Vuejs is telling you that the error is coming from ` import navigationbottom from './components/navigation/bottom'` please share the contents of that file

Comment: Found it, i had <templat> instead of <template> uhumm sorry and many tnx! Works!